# Is it possible to simulate a SSHD

Tags: windows, ssd

Is it possible to simulate a SSHD by using an existing HDD, a small SSD, and some disk caching software. Most caching software (Intel SRT, Nvelo's Dataplex, etc) seems hardware dependent, and the software seems to be not available separately.

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Including, even if it can be done, is it worth it?

Thanks

Comment: Hey Your question seems to be similar to mine (http://superuser.com/questions/830025/creating-a-ramdisk-on-windows-to-cache-hdd). Just posting to receive updates from this thread.

Comment: What problem exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Ramhound: The OP's trying to use an SSD as a cache.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/q/390071/85308