# How can I use my an SSD partition as a cache for a large HDD on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, cache

I have a 480gb SSD on with installed Windows 10 and Applications. However i also have a 2.5TB (and growing) steam/gog Game Library currently on a HDD that i'd like to cache with a >=256GB partition from the SSD. Which *software* can i use to accomplish this?

And no, i don't want install specific games on my ssd and i don't have $1200 for two 2TB SDDs...

[This other superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/390071/how-can-i-use-my-small-ssd-as-a-cache-for-a-larger-hard-disk) has some cool advice but it either requires special hardware or isn't relevant for windows 10.

Comment: Well it seems it can be done with Intel SRT (https://communities.intel.com/thread/99954?start=0&tstart=0) but i'd rather use something that isn't dependant on the chipset

Comment: I haven't done much research, but Storage Spaces (at least in the Server edition of Windows) supports tiered storage, and using SSD for caching.  Don't know if that is available on Win10 though.

Comment: Thanks, looks like this works, however it has no gui and is unsupported. And it has to be done via powershell :) see http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/does-windows-10-support-tiered-storage/bd9df89c-572b-4630-96e9-4606de7c3162 & https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2015/12/21/recovering-from-failed-disks-in-tiered-storage-spaces-on-windows-10-via-powershell/