# Windows equivalent of lvm-cache

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, cache

I'm going to be using Windows 7 for a few months on a custom built x86_64 Intel-based platform with Z97 motherboard. Being an avid linux user, I was wondering:

> does Windows have any form of managed caching, like lvm-cache or bcache?

I really like this feature and would like to  set up HDD caching with an SSD with Win7. Is it possible?

@edit: I will take into consideration solutions provided via 3rd party apps, both free and paid.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/93538/how-can-i-use-my-ssd-as-a-readyboost-cache-disk

Comment: It is a cross post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37775661/windows-equivalent-of-lvm-cache

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/568719/174557